# controller method is not working and page is refreshing instead of redirecting to given path in laravel

Tags: laravel, post, controller, laravel-blade

I am not getting any error, it's just refreshing on that page. The controller method is not called where I have given the path for redirection.
My code is:

**blade-file**

```
 <form action="{{route('validate-promocode')}}" method="post">
                      @csrf
                    <input class="promo-input" id="code" type="text" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" name="code" placeholder="EG. APPLY HERE"><br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!!csrf_token()!!}">
                    <button id="save" type="submit" class="apply-promo">Apply Promo Code</button>
                    </form>
```

**Route file**

```
Route::post('/validade-code', 'PromoController@validateCode')->name('validate-promocode');
```

**Controller file**

```
public function validateCode(Request $request){
      if (Gate::allows('isUser')) {
          $ip = $request->input('code');
          dd($promo);
        $promo = Promo::where('code','=', trim($ip))->first();

        if(!empty($promo)){
          $dataamountMonthly =  40000  - (($promo->discount_percentage * 40000) / 100);
          $dataamountYearly  =  300000  - (($promo->discount_percentage * 300000) / 100);

          if($dataamountMonthly == 0 || $dataamountYearly == 0){


            return view('paymet.subscription-success');
        }
          $data = array(
              'dataamountMonthly' => $dataamountMonthly ,
              'dataamountYearly'  => $dataamountYearly,
              'code' => $ip
          );

          return view('payment.startPromoCode',$data);

        }else{
          $data = array(
              'error' => 'Something went wrong, please try again'
          );
         return redirect()->back()->with($data);
        }
      }
  }
```

I don't know what I am missing , any help will be appriciated.

Comment: @lagbox I have done this for all other views in my code , the problem is here it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved** 
Sometimes you may wish to redirect the user to their previous location, such as when a submitted form is invalid. You may do so by using the global back helper function. Since this feature utilizes the session, make sure the route calling the back function is using the web middleware group or has all of the session middleware applied

Comment: its not a issue

Comment: Sometimes you may wish to redirect the user to their previous location, such as when a submitted form is invalid. You may do so by using the global back helper function. Since **this feature utilizes the session**, make sure **the route calling the back function is using the web middleware group or has all of the session middleware applied**

Comment: yeah the issue is that I have not check for the middleware. Now I get the solution, thanks anyway for helping!:P

Comment: Happy Coding !!

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark this as accepted answer. Also you might want to fix the typo in your route "/validade-code" -> should be "/validate-code"

Answer (score 0):

I think according to your code

```
$promo = Promo::where('code','=', trim($ip))->first();
```

the value of `$promo` can be `null/ empty`

and instead of executing your expected code it is redirecting back the page, and it seems the **refresh** for you. rest your code is correct.

Comment: its not null value, problem is method from controller is not working

Comment: pass the csrf token only once your adding twice